# Двойные ковычки json ajax

Tags: javascript, цифровая-подпись

Пишу создание запроса на сертификат квал.ЭП. Отправляю созданный запрос в УЦ, он парсится на их стороне, сравнивается с их заявкой и возвращает мне ошибку связанную с именем организации(проблема в кавычках).

часть моего JSON:

```
var Dn = {
'2.5.4.3' :"ООО \"Рога и копыта\"",
'2.5.4.10':"ООО \"Рога и копыта\"",
...
};
```

После отправки запроса на сервер получаю ошибку: Название организации в **запросе "ООО Рога и копыта"** не соответствует данным в **заявке "ООО "Рога и копыта""**.

Видно, что на каком-то этапе теряются ковычки у Рога и копыта.

Пробовал различные варианты экранирования, пробовал и одинарные и двойные - ошибка не исчезла.
Прошу подсказать

Comment: А что если писать `'ООО "Рога и копыта"',` ?

Comment: Пробовал. Не помогает.

Comment: Либо им надо `"\"ООО \"Рога и копыта\"\""` :D

Comment: ошибка не меняется)

Comment: json  же просто преобразует к строке, типа tyString() Странно, что там вообще ошибка.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать объявление по W3C:

```
key: "  %22ООО  %22Рога и копыта    %22 %22 "
```

Comment: Cпасибо, проверил. Ошибка: "%22ООО  %22Рога и копыта    %22 %22" не соответствует данным в заявке: "ООО "Рога и копыта""

Comment: ООО не может быть в другой раскладке?

Comment: @OliverPatterson проверил, кодировки одинаковые.